# How can you define the items of an array in a markup extension?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I wrote a custom WPF markup extension that formats a string. It looks like this:

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace MarkupExtensions;

public class InterpolationExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public object[] Arguments { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (Arguments is not null)
            return string.Format((string)Value, Arguments);

        return null;
    }

    public InterpolationExtension(object value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public InterpolationExtension()
    {

    }
}
```

But if I want to use this in XAML, I have to use this clunky syntax (`GreetMultiple` is just a string resource `"Hello, {0}, {1} and {2}!"`:

```xml
            <Run>
                <Run.Text>
                    <e:Interpolation>
                        <e:Interpolation.Value>
                            <StaticResource ResourceKey="GreetMultiple"/>
                        </e:Interpolation.Value>
                        
                        <e:Interpolation.Arguments>
                            <x:Array Type="{x:Type sys:String}">
                                <sys:String>A</sys:String>
                                <sys:String>B</sys:String>
                                <sys:String>C</sys:String>
                            </x:Array>
                        </e:Interpolation.Arguments>
                    </e:Interpolation>
                </Run.Text>
            </Run>
```

Is there some way to specify the array elements in one line like this?

```xml
<Run Text="{e:Interpolation Value={StaticResource GreetMultiple}, Arguments={x:Array Type={x:Type sys:String}, Items=[A,B,C]}}"/>
```

Everything about this works except for the `[ ]` syntax.

Comment: "*It looks like this*" -- no it doesn't. The code you posted has a syntax error. Please post code which you've actually run, and made sure that it reproduces your problem

Comment: There's no syntax for declaring an array using a markup extension I'm afraid.

Comment: That's a shame. But I don't know which syntax error you are talking about. I copied the code over directly from my IDE and it runs. The 2nd code box only shows a part of the XAML of course and the 3rd is fictional.

Comment: Your `ProvideValue` method has code paths which don't contain a `return` statement, so this class will not compile.

Comment: Yes, you're right. That's from a previous state where I had a single string property. I removed it here for clarity. I'll edit the post.

Comment: Right, so you didn't "copy the code over directly from your IDE". It hasn't affected this question, but we see so many questions where the asker has edited their code before posting, and hasn't checked to see whether their edited code still reproduces the problem. And so we end up trying to diagnose a problem which doesn't actually exist, as written in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MarkupExtension to symplify the construction of array as well.

The MarkupExtension below can handle up to 5 elements buf if you need  more elements, add more constructors.

```cs
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(object[]))]
public class ArrayConstructorExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    private readonly object[] _elements;

    public ArrayConstructorExtension(object a) => _elements = new[] { a };
    public ArrayConstructorExtension(object a, object b) => _elements = new[] { a, b };
    public ArrayConstructorExtension(object a, object b, object c) => _elements = new[] { a, b, c };
    public ArrayConstructorExtension(object a, object b, object c, object d) => _elements = new[] { a, b, c, d };
    public ArrayConstructorExtension(object a, object b, object c, object d, object e) => _elements = new[] { a, b, c, d, e };

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return _elements;
    }
}
```

Then it can be used as follows:

```xml
<Run Text="{e:Interpolation Value={StaticResource GreetMultiple}, Arguments={e:ArrayConstructor A, B, C}}"/>
```